# Guard statement with two conditions in Swift

Tags: swift, mkannotation, guard

My understanding is that having two conditions in a guard statement separated by a comma functions imposes the requirement that they both be true.  I can write a guard statement with either one independently and the code compiles but when I combine them with a comma, it gives an error. Is there anything wrong with my syntax or can anyone explain why it fails to compile?

```
guard (mode != "mapme") else {  //compiles
}

guard (!annotation is MKUserLocation) else { //compiles
}

guard (mode != "mapme",!(annotation is MKUserLocation)) else { //gives error:'(Bool, Bool)' is not convertible to 'Bool'

}
```

Comment: Check parentheses!

Comment: Remove the outer (). Generally Boolean clauses in Swift do not require parentheses

Comment: comma separates expressions from each other. You cannot put parentheses around 2 expressions separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using too many pointless parentheses, basically don't use parentheses in `if` and `guard` statements in *simple* expressions.

The error occurs because the compiler treats the enclosing parentheses as tuple (`(Bool, Bool)`), that's what the error message says.

```
guard mode != "mapme" else {

guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { // here the parentheses are useful but the `!` must be outside of the expression

guard mode != "mapme", !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
```

Comment: This now compiles but is not giving me the right logic.  I don't want to run else code when both statements are true: 1)  !(annotation is MKUserLocation) ie the annotation is not the user annotation and  2) mode != "mapme" ie the mode is not mapme.  I want to run the else code if either the mode is "mapme" or the annotation is the MKUserlocation.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually this is the logic. If `mode == "mapme"` **or** `annotation is MKUserLocation` then the code in the `else` cause is executed and the scope is left otherwise the code after the closing `}` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use parenthesis, just use && operator (or || if you want an OR clause)

```
guard (mode != "mapme" && !(annotation is MKUserLocation)) else {
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift you do not need the outer brackets on, if statements, for loops and all that. It is generally considered good practice not to include them, in your case here the guard statement becomes a tuple when you include the brackets. So just change your code to this and it should all work.

```
guard mode != "mapme" else {  //compiles
}

guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { //compiles
}

guard mode != "mapme", !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { 

}
```